# Calling method of objects in array using map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out a one-liner code using `map`.

Here is a simple set up.

```
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // FYI: using __proto__ is discouraged. thanks @KarelG
    this.__proto__.mew = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " mews");
    };
}

var cats = [
    new Cat('MB'),
    new Cat('503')
];
```

Then, I can use `map()` to call `mew` method in cats.

```
cats.map(function (cat) {
    cat.mew();
});
// MB mews
// 503 mews
```

`call()` on prototype also works.

```
cats.map(function (cat) {
    Cat.prototype.mew.call(cat);
});
// MB mews
// 503 mews
```

And here is my final one-liner, but it emits error and I could't understand why:

```
cats.map(Cat.prototype.mew.call);

// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
// at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Checking `typeof Cat.prototype.mew.call` says it's a `function`
and `map()`'s parameter should be a function.

Could anyone explain why it doesn't work? 
What did I miss and where to correct?

Comment: yes it should be like `cats.map((Cat) => Cat.mew.call());` or like `cats.map(function(Cat) { Cat.mew.call()});`

Comment: just fyi, adding functions to the internal `[[Prototype]]` using `__proto__` is discouraged (mainly due of the nature of prototypes which may impact the performance). Even if there is a function in favor of that `__proto__` (the function is `Object.setPrototypeOf()`), I should not use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could anyone explain why it doesn't work? What did I miss and where to
>   correct?

Error message says

> VM1100:15 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This means that it is looking to *call the `mew` method* on a context which is `undefined`.

You need to bind the context as

```
cats.map( Cat.prototype.mew.call.bind( new Cat().mew ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.__proto__.mew = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " mews");
    };
}

var cats = [
    new Cat('MB'),
    new Cat('503')
];
cats.map( Cat.prototype.mew.call.bind( new Cat().mew ) );
```

Or as @PatrickRoberts has suggested, you can use

```
cats.map(Function.call.bind(Cat.prototype.mew))
```

to avoid needlessly creating an instance of `Cat`

> In `cats.map(function (cat) { Cat.prototype.mew.call(cat); });`
>   expression, **why `Cat.prototype.mew.call` has a correct context?**

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map)

> If a thisArg parameter is provided, it will be used as the this value
>   for each invocation of callbackfn. If it is not provided, undefined is
>   used instead.

So, unless you pass a context like

```
cats.map( Cat.prototype.mew.call,  new Cat().mew );
```

It will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, your code works. In `cats.map(function (cat) { Cat.prototype.mew.call(cat); });` expression, why `Cat.prototype.mew.call` has a correct context?

Comment: `cats.map(Function.call.bind(Cat.prototype.mew))` would avoid needlessly constructing an instance of `Cat`

Comment: @Kita in map (as per spec), unless the context is passed explicitly, it is taken as undefined.